# Using Predicate<T> or a Func<T> in method to filter

Tags: c#

Using NET Core 2.2 I have the following:

```
public class User {
  public virtual IEnumerable<Claim> Claims { get; }
}

public class Claim { 
  public String Type { get; set; }
  public String Value { get; set; }
}
```

And I have an UserService with a method `FindAllClaims`:

```
public class UserService {

  public IEnumerable<Claim> FindAllClaims(/* Some Filter */) {
  }

}
```

I would like to being able to filter claims in `FindAllClaims` method:

```
User user = this.User;

user.FindAllClaims(x => x.Type == "sub");
```

I am not sure the best way to do this ...

Using `Predicate<Claim>` or a `Func<Claim>` in `FindAllClaims` method?

How would I do this?

Comment: FYI: The Predicate<Claim> == Func<Claim,bool>

Comment: Func is used When you want a delegate for a function that may or may not take parameters and returns a value.  e.g. Select from LINQ
Predicate is used When you want a specialized version of a Func that evaluates a value against a set of criteria and returns a boolean result (true for a match, false otherwise) 
Better to go with Predicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```cs
public IEnumerable<Claim> FindAllClaims(this IEnumerable<Claim> source, 
    Expression<Predicate<Claim>> condition)
{
    return source.Where(condition);
}
```

or

```cs
public IEnumerable<Claim> FindAllClaims(this IEnumerable<Claim> source, 
    Expression<Func<Claim,bool>> condition)
{
    return source.Where(condition);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`Predicate<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?view=netframework-4.8) delegate is defined as

```
public delegate bool Predicate<in T>(T obj);
```

The [`Func<T,TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netframework-4.8) delegate is defined as

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T,out TResult>(T arg);
```

Therefor, a `Func<T, bool>` is equivalent to `Predicate<T>`.

That being said, I would go with `Predicate` on this one, since it conveys the intent of the argument better than a `Func`.

Note, however, that the `TResult` of the `Func` delegate is marked as `out`, so if you're using a reference type, you can return anything that implements the `TResult` interface, or derived from the `TResult` class.
For more information, read the [Variance in Generic Type Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-delegates#variance-in-generic-type-parameters) paragraph in the [Variance in Delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-delegates) documentation.